# How does this unsigned long long translate to being a point to evaluate prime numbers from 3-100 in this for loop?

Tags: c

```
int main()

{

puts('2');

for (unsigned long long b = 04224646226462667ull, p = 3; b; p += 2, b /= 2)

if (b % 2) printf("%lld\n", p);

return 0;

}
```

I found this online on a post where someone was trying to screw with a kid soliciting homework solutions, and for the life of me, I can't figure it out. I understand it probably has something to do with the integer division performed on the unsigned long long, but other than that, I fail to see what's facilitating it's exclusion of the certain values in the range through 100.

Comment: Debug it once. All will be clear.

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica

I did, yet wasn't left very satisfied with my understanding how that constant correlates. I am not inept, and can debug code. I don't doubt I'm missing something rather simple, but simultaneously wouldn't have posted this here if I didn't stare at it for long enough to be confused.

Comment: It's an octal literal. Did you notice *that* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, first thing I did was convert it, and really don't see anything super special about the integer 150964650272183.

Comment: Nit.. technically your `puts('2');` must be `puts("2");`

Comment: note that the above code has UB in `printf("%lld\n", p);` because p is an `unsigned long long` which must be printed using `%llu`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I knew that, I was just testing you. 
I quickly copied it off vim, and didn't grab that line, so I trusted myself to type it without needing gcc to tell me to go write that crap in a python interpreter.

Comment: @EricLang no worries, as long as you have `100010010100110100110010010110100110010110110111` figured out and how it is just a simple odd count starting from 3 at the right and outputting the value for each `1-bit` that is set, you are good to go. (it was a cruel way to tell a student how to generate primes from 1-100....)

Comment: Chuckling.... yuck! Don't throw me in that java brier-patch.. Thankfully my first programming class came a year or two after A&M got rid of the punch-card readers and had a shiny new Vax system. FORTRAN on a Vax was a step up from keeping punch cards in order... Then I went to work at JSC in '89 and we had Sun with C! But then how to move 750K lines of FORTAN to C... Ouch -- thank goodness for contractors.... Fast forward 30 years and son is at A&M, and programming has moved to microcontrollers -- but at least it is C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author has effectively buried the prime sequence in a constant based on the fact that

1. There are fewer than 63 primes between 2 and 100, so an encoding used 64bits of a ULL can be used.
2. Starting with 3, it navigates only odd numbers between 3 and 99 inclusively. Since there are only 49 such numbers in 3...99, we have plenty of bits to encode with.
3. Each iteration effectively does a right-shift of `b` by one bit (with `b /= 2`).

Therefore, by encoding the constant such that the zero bit of `b` is lit on the current iteration if the value `p` is a prime, and you only print `p` in that specific case, The result is a list of numbers that detail exactly what was encoded, and nothing more. In this case that encoding was primes, but that the numbers are primes have nothing to do with the actual math; it's all about the pre-determine encoding, the bit shift, and reporting a counter if that first bit is lit after the shift.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a somewhat less oblique version of it:

```
int main()
{
#define bit(n)  (1ull<<(n))
    unsigned long long bitmask = 04224646226462667ull;
    puts("2");

    for (int i=0; bit(i) < bitmask; i++)
        if (bitmask & bit(i))
            printf("%u\n", 3 + i*2);

    return 0;
}
```

So the funny literal is a compressed encoding of the prime numbers between 3 and 100.  The compression eliminates all the even numbers (obviously not prime), so that if bit i is set, then the corresponding prime number is 3 + i * 2.